# values returned as unique identifier

Tags: fields

I'm using a a HTML table with a  component to display values from the Lead object. The custom controller retunr som values as ID unique identifier What can I do if I want to pull the actual value on that field?

Answer (score 1):

You can add relationship queries in your soql to pull name

Example:

Contact c=[Select Id,Name,Account.Name from Contact limit 1];

Now if its getter then simply pull using {!c.Account.Name}